# Differences in distance calculated between javascript function and sql server STD distance

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2012, geospatial

```
DECLARE @orig geography = geography::Point(17, 78, 4326);     
Select  @orig.STDistance(geography::Point(17.001, 78.00001, 4326))/1000
```

gives

110.674385214845

```
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, units) {
        var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
        var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1);  // deg2rad below
        var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        var d = R * c; // Distance in km
        return d;
}
function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
}`
```

gives
0.11120001099379416 km

difference of 0.6 mtrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) you have used above assumes a spherical earth, with a circumference of 6371 km whereas the Geography datatype uses the [WGS 84 ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). The main difference between the two is that in WGS 84 the earth is an oblate spheroid (ie, squashed at the poles) and is assumed to have a circumference of 6378.13 km around the equator, but a circumference of 6356.75 km around the poles. The full equations for calculations using the WGS 84 ellipsoid are quite complex and Haversine is considered a good approximation in most circumstances.

If you look at the introduction to this excellent resource, http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, the author makes this exact point and suggests that the error from ignoring the ellipsoid is about 0.3% on average (yours is around 0.4%). I repeat the author's quote here, just in case the page ever goes down.

> All these formulæ are for calculations on the basis of a spherical earth (ignoring ellipsoidal effects) – which is accurate enough* for most purposes… [In fact, the earth is very slightly ellipsoidal; using a spherical model gives errors typically up to 0.3% – see notes for further details].